# How to disable mouse events over a certain area

Tags: java, javafx, mouseevent

So what I have is a smaller Pane inside a larger Pane, and what I want to do is enable/disable any handling of mouse events over that smaller pane. That would be done in theory by setting the mouse events of the smaller pane and all its children to *null*, and then restoring them later. But this is tedious and I was wondering if there is a simpler way.

Could I set a transparent Pane over that smaller pane to "capture" the mouse clicks for that area? Any suggestion is appreciated. btw I am working in javafx.

Comment: `pane.setDisable(true)`?

Comment: that works? would be awesome

Comment: Why wouldn't it work?

Comment: idk lemme try it

Comment: seems to work. thanks anon

Comment: I mean James_D lmao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a event filter for the `smallPane` and consume mouse events for `smallPane` and it's decendants:

```
EventHandler<MouseEvent> handler = MouseEvent::consume;

// block events
smallPane.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, handler);
```

to reenable remove the event filter later you can do

```
smallPane.removeEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, handler);
```

---

This way you disable just mouse events, not `KeyEvent`s, ect...

Answer (score 4):

You can just disable the pane:

```
smallPane.setDisable(true);
```

which will also disable any of its child nodes. (See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#disableProperty), which says "Setting disable to true will cause this `Node` and any subnodes to become disabled.").

To enable it again, just do

```
smallPane.setDisable(false);
```